# Eject an unformatted external HDD

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, veracrypt

I have a big external USB HDD, which is device-encrypted with Veracrypt. That means when I plug it in, Ubuntu just sees an empty, unpartitioned raw device.

> > lsblk  -h
>
> sdb           8:16   0   2,7T  0 disk

Question is now, how do I safely remove it from my computer? Back when it was unencrypt it, I would just eject it from nautilus and it would shutdown. Now I have to forcefully pull the plug, and the HDD screams in agony when I do.

After much googling I came across this command:

```
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb
```

A bit cumbersome. But it works - sdb is powered down. For a split second. And then it is powered up immediately again...

Comment: You could try the good old `eject`, `eject /dev/sdb`.

Comment: Doesnt work -  it unmounts any partitions on that volume but doesnt shutdown/poweroff the HDD.

Comment: Not being accessed is all you need to safely remove the drive. If nothing is mounted go ahead.

Comment: I  cant safely remove it, because it's not formatted at all and so does not show up in the file manager (safely remove = clicking the eject button next to the drives name in nautilus?).